# Using "\n" properly for echo statement

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

We are using Woocommerce for our ecommerce platform and we have encountered a problem with the order emails where sometimes the link is too long and it breaks when a customer tries to click the link to start their digital download.

I did some research and found out you could counter this problem by placing "\n" within the link section of the order emails.

While doing a test it looks like it worked but it is actually printing the \n before the text of my link.

So for example this is how I have it in the template file:

```
echo ' <a href="' . $download_file_url . '" target="_blank">\n' . $filename . '</a></small>';
```

But this is how it looks on the customer email: Download 1: \nMy-Customer-Download.m4v

Am I using it properly?

The reason I need to do that is because if the links are too big for some of the downloads then some mail clients will insert a %20 randomly in some of the links, I guess to break it up for display in the email.  So after researching some solutions I saw some people were able to correct this by using the "\n" within the content of the email to break it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables/escaped characters do not expand in single quotes.

If you want to use a `\n` character you have to use double quotes:

```
echo 'No new\nline';
echo "Yes new\nline";
```

Output:

> No new\nlineYes new
>   line

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/rheb3dL7)

Alternatively, you can always use

```
echo 'Single quote string with' . "\n" . ' newline!';
```

or use [`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol):

```
echo 'Single quote string with' . PHP_EOL . ' newline!';
```

Comment: Thanks man, do would it look like this then? 'echo ' <a href="' . $download_file_url . '" target="_blank">'."\n" . $filename . '</a></small>';'

Comment: @Derek Yeah - that'd work fine. So would `PHP_EOL` or saving `\n` to a variable. The possibilities are endless. :)

Comment: Thanks so much, it's always the little things -- worked perfectly :)